# Passing pointer from Derived class to a Base class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I'm trying to pass a pointer that points to a Derived class to a Base class constructor when creating an object. Here is the scenario:

```
class Base
{
public:
    // Default constructor
    Base(Base* base_ptr = nullptr)
    {
        cout << base_ptr << endl;
        base_ptr->foo();
    }
    virtual void foo() { cout << "Base foo" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived* derived_ptr;

    Derived() : derived_ptr(this), Base(this)
    {
        cout << derived_ptr << endl;
        derived_ptr->foo();
    }

    virtual void foo() override { cout << "Derived foo" << endl; }
 };
```

In main.cpp:

```
...

Derived derived;

...
```

1 .  Why does it print out the exact same memory for base_ptr and derived_ptr,    but a different method of Foo() is called for each constructor ?

2 .  If in initializer list for Derived() instead of Base(this) i do Base(derived_ptr), why does it pass in some junk ?

Comment: Look at virtual call in constructor/destructor.

Comment: Take a look at [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2069064). There's a lot you have to learn about initialization order and how `virtual` works.

Comment: For 2: You may got warning for `derived_ptr(this), Base(this)` which is in fact `Base(this), derived_ptr(this)`, and so `Base` constructor is called before `derived_ptr` initialization.

Comment: As a rule of thumb - the only thing you are allowed to do with a pointer to a derived class in the constructor of the base class is store it but **not** use it in any way. And even that earns you a warning, usually.